# Does C guarantee 32-bit integer arithmetic?

Tags: c

In C, suppose `int` is 32 bit,

```
uint64_t x = 1000000u * 1000000u;
```

this is commonly implemented by multiplying the numbers for a 32-bit result, discarding overflow bits, then assigning with zero extension to `x`.

Does the language guarantee this, or could the compiler instead choose to do everything in 64 bits, giving the mathematically accurate result?

(I know the language standard allows `int` to be 64 bit in the first place. I'm talking specifically about the situation where `int` is 32 bit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Standard guarantees this—if the operands are 32 bits wide.  In C11, [the Standard says:](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A116%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D)

> A  computation  involving  unsigned  operands  can  never  overflow, because  a  result  that  cannot  be  represented  by  the  resulting  unsigned  integer  type  is reduced  modulo  the  number  that  is  one  greater  than  the  largest  value  that  can  be represented by the resulting type.

This is reiterated in Annex H of C11:

> C’s unsigned integer types are “modulo” in the LIA−1 sense in that overflows or out-of-bounds results silently wrap.

So, the result of an unsigned multiplication that overflows is to throw out the upper bits of the result.

If you do not want this behavior, the workaround is to write at least one constant as `1000000ULL`, guaranteeing that the intermediate result will be promoted to at least 64 bits.  You could also put an explicit cast in front of one of the operands, e.g. `(uint_fast64_t)1000000`, if you wanted.

If you want to guarantee it, write both operands as `((uint32_t)1000000UL)`.  This type, if it exists, *must* be exactly 32 bits wide.

However, I do not recommend having your program depend implicitly on subtle implicit behavior that varies between implementations.  You could make it much clearer to anyone maintaining it with code like:

```
static const uint32_t multiplicand = 1000000UL;
static const uint64_t product_low_word = multiplicand * multiplicand; // Upper 32 bits cleared.
```

Comment: Link for your quote:  https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p9  I was looking for that...

Comment: @AndrewHenle Added a link to open-std.org.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  The cert is from `CN = RapidSSL SHA256 CA O = GeoTrust Inc. C = US`  See https://knowledge.digicert.com/alerts/ALERT2562.html for why.  I'm guessing that the private key for the site was one of the ones leaked by Symantec (owner of RapidSSL)

Answer (score 4):

```
uint64_t x = 1000000u * 1000000u;
```

Your stated assumption is that `int` is 32 bits. To be 100% clear, we need to assume that `UINT_MAX` is 2<sup>32</sup>-1, or `4294967295`. (The standard requires `unsigned int` to have a range of at least 0 to 65535, which implies a size of at least 16 bits -- but it can have *padding bits*.) It's almost certainly the same thing (I don't know of any C implementations that have padding bits), but we should be explicit if we want to ask what the standard guarantees.

Given that assumption, the constant `1000000u` is of type `unsigned int`, and the result of the multiplication is `3567587328u`, also of type `unsigned int`. That value is converted to `uint64_t` (with no loss of information) and stored in `x`.

`uint64_t` is guaranteed to be exactly 64 bits wide with no padding bits. An implementation that doesn't have a type that satisfies those conditions will not define `uint64_t`, so the above wouldn't compile. (I'm assuming, of course, that this refers to the `uint64_t` defined in the standard `<stdint.h>` or `<inttypes.h>` header.)

The general rule for arithmetic expressions is that the type of an expression is determined by the types of its operands, not by the values of its operands or the context in which it appears. If we drop the assumption about the upper bound of `unsigned int`, the constant `1000000u` could be of type `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`, whichever type is big enough to hold it -- but the value of the product is the same as the type of the constants, even if that results in <strike>overflow</strike> wraparound. (Strictly speaking, unsigned operations don't overflow.)

Comment: *Your stated assumption is that `int` is 32 bits.*  The presence of `uint64_t` requires a two's-complement machine with no padding, doesn't it? *the result of the multiplication is 3567587328u*  I assume that's because the bits in excess of 32 are truncated?  (I haven't done the math)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The standard doesn't prevent a conforming implementation from using different representations for different types. `uint64_t`, if it exists, must be 64 bits with no padding bits. The standard requires an implementation that provides `uint64_t` to also provide `int64_t`, which implies that it must have a 64-bit 2's-complement integer type with no padding bits (I'm not a fan of this requirement, but there it is). But it would be legal for an implementation to have `uint64_t` and to have padding bits for `int` and `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, assuming `unsigned int` is 32 bits.

Per [**6.5.5 Multiplicative operators**, paragraph 3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p3):

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.

Those conversions per [**6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) are:

> This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions:
>
> - First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is long double, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain,
>     to a type whose corresponding real type is long double.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain,
>     to a type whose corresponding real type is double.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is float, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain,
>     to a type whose corresponding real type is float.62)
> - Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
>   - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>   - Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer
>       conversion rank is converted to the type of the operand with greater
>       rank.
>   - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>       the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>       operand with unsigned integer type.
>   - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>       integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted
>       to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>   - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer
>       type.

Note "If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed."

Since both operands are the same type - `unsigned int`, the result of your multiplication operation will be `unsigned int` for any conforming compiler.

[EXAMPLE 2 from **5.1.2.3 Program execution**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p11) is informative on how strictly arithmetic operations must be treated ([EXAMPLE 6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p15) is even better, but it's too long IMO to effectively quote):

> EXAMPLE 2 In executing the fragment
>
> ```
>       char c1, c2;
>       /* ... */
>       c1 = c1 + c2;
> ```
>
> the ''integer promotions'' require that the abstract machine promote
>   the value of each variable to int size and then add the two ints and
>   truncate the sum. Provided the addition of two chars can be done
>   without overflow, or with overflow wrapping silently to produce the
>   correct result, the actual execution need only produce the same
>   result, possibly omitting the promotions.

Answer (score 2):

It's required to do it as modular arithmetic in whatever type `unsigned` is on the C implementation you're using. With your assumption that it's a 32-bit type, the result must be 32-bit. This would not necessarily apply in other superficially-similar examples where different type promotion rules might apply.

Answer (score 2):

The operation `1000000u * 1000000u` has precedence over the assignment and occurs independently of it.  Where `unsigned int` is 32 bit, this will be a 32 bit unsigned result regardless of the type of `x`.